# Overriding abstract list<a> property with list<A>

Tags: c#, abstract, overriding

I'm writing a piece of code to make certain reports. There are 4 types of reports which the user can request. Each type report is based on the base class 'report'. Each derived class has a List. The class 'A' is derived from base class 'a'.

Is it possible to add an abstract List to the 'report' class and let it be overridden by a List in the derived report classes? Something like this?

```
public abstract class Report
{
  public abstract List<a> Coils { get; set; }
}

public class ProductionExitCoilReport : Report
{
  public override List<A> Coils { get; set; }             
}

public class a
{
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class A: a
{
  public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }             
}
```

I'm kind of new to C# so if I'm asking something really basic or I have a big flaw in my thinking, please do point it out. But please don't just answer with yes or no.

Comment: If you want to be able to change the type down the inheritance hierarchy, then research generics (e.g. `List<T>`). You can't do it like your code above, it won't compile. Without knowing more about why you want to do this kind of thing, it's hard to offer more specific advice.

Comment: Make `Report` generic for the type of report: `class Report<T> where T : a` and make the `Coils` property hold a list of that report type: `List<T> Coils`. Unfortunately, without knowing which problem you're trying to solve, this is probably not going to be the right solution nor helpful. Please explain why you need this inheritance and override situation to begin with.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i think you should write this as an answer so OP can see how it works. He has the right ideas and doesnt know how generic classes work.

Comment: Until I'm convinced this is actually what OP wants I'm not going to post this as an answer. You're free to do so, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description of the usage, there is no need to override the List/collection in your new class. Since A inherits from a, you can store objects of type A in "Coils". (due to polymorphism). Then if, at some later time, you want to access "SomeOtherProperty" of the objects of type A, you could use a cast.

```
public abstract class Report
{
    public List<a> Coils { get; set; }
}

public class ProductionExitCoilReport : Report
{

}

public class a
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class A : a
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    //to store the coil
    ProductionExitCoilReport myReport = new ProductionExitCoilReport();
    myReport.Coils.Add(new A());

    //to retreive SomeOtherProperty from the first element in the list
    string retrievedProperty = ((A)myReport.Coils[0]).SomeOtherProperty;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!
I thought it worked the other way, that you can only save base classes in derived classes since derived classes have more properties than the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Your properties are readable and writable.

Derived types must always be compatible with the base type.

Every `Report` has `Coils` property that returns a read/write collections of items of type `a`. Thus you can always write `report.Coils.Add(new a())`.

`ProductionExitCoilReport` inherits from `Report`, so it would have been possible to run the same code - to add `a` (not `A`) to the collection returned by `Coils`: `((Report)productionReport).Coils.Add(new a())`.

This contradicts what you want to accomplish.

Please read about [covariance and contravariance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/page/2/):